# Akka log info does not print anything although LogLevel is set to DEBUG

Tags: logging, playframework, akka

I don't manage to find why my Slf4j Logger does not print the info messages. For instance, when I'm doing:

```
log info "info"
log error "error"
```

Only the error message in printed. I think this is a configuration problem, but I don't find where...
I'm using `Akka 2.4` with `akka-slf4j 2.4`.

My `application.conf` file (I use actors inside a Play! application) is:

```
akka {
loglevel = DEBUG
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"

  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    debug {
      receive = on
      lifecycle = on
    }
  }

  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2553
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put one `logback.xml` under your resource folder (next to application.conf), I used the following content, and worked for me

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%highlight(%-5level)] %cyan(%logger{5}): %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="application" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="akka" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="mypackage" level="INFO" />

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```